Is it possible to include two AR process in a GAMM?
I am trying to model the presence/absence of a specie in function of environmental variables. My dataset is composed of hourly observation of 126 animals and the environmental conditions when the observation is made (resulting in a 300k rows dataset). 
To model the relation between my animals and the environmental variables, I used the bam() function, included a cyclic spline in smooth of the temporal variable (s(time, bs = "cc")), and an AR1 process (rho = ...). This AR process significantly improved the distribution of my residuals, but the model still presents a residual 12 hours cycle unaddressed. 


I suspect this cycle to originate from the tidal cycle my specie is subjected to. A variable specifying the time to high tide is included with a cyclic spline in the model, but it doesn't tackle the 12 hours cycle. I have tried to include a second correlation parameter using rho = c(AR1, AR12) but it returned an error requesting only one value.
Is it possible to include this second correlation parameter and if yes how?

How about a cyclic spline on hour-of-day?

Agree with Ben Bolker; you cannot include multiple lags in bam() but it seems you need a cyclic smooth to capture the daily seasonality in your outcome. Look at documentation for the cyclic basis and also see here for some guidance

Thank you both for your answers, unfortunately, I had already included a cyclic spline in my model (I edited the post to include this information and a few others). @Nicholas Clark you wrote it is not possible to include multiple lags in bam() and using gamm()is not an option either as it is way too computationally intensive. Do you know other function that could do that? You mentioned in another post the package you wrote, can it do that?

No unfortunately {mvgam} also cannot fit lag-12 AR models either. But I think you need to create a variable for hour of the day, as Ben suggested, and then fit the cyclic smooth for that variable (rather than for time)
